# iPhone: Phone Number UITextView vs UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITableView`. In row I need to setup text, so I need to use `UILabel` or `UITextView`. I need to detect phone number in text, so I use `UITextView`. BUT I need to set text only in 2 lines and if it's longer, setup ellipses in the end , because row height isn't big, so that work `UILabel` do perfect. So how to be ??? Can `UILabel` detect phone number ? or can i set `UITextView` in 2 lines and set ellipses in the end ?? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that the UITextView has a property that let you set ellipses at the end if the text is to long. However that is simple to fix:

[NSString documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

You could use this method if all you want to do is to allow let say 120 characters, and starting from 0.

> **substringToIndex:**
>
> Returns a new string containing the
> characters of the receiver up to, but
> not including, the one at a given
> index.
>
> (NSString *)substringToIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex

```
NSString *shortText = 
          [[someLongTextVariable substringToIndex: 120] stringWithString:@"..."];
```

Maybe you should use a mutable string for this, I do not know what performes the best. But if you do this, you could atleast detect phone numbers.